# cumsum of groups in r dataframe excluding the first value

Tags: r, cumulative-sum, cumsum

I have a dataframe with groups which are defined by a factor value. I am trying to add a column with the cumulative sum based on each individual group.

```
bbb<-c(2,4,6,3,5,7)
factor<-gl(2,3)
df<-data.frame(bbb,factor)
```

I have found the ave() function and have successfully used it, like this:

```
df$cumbbb<-ave(df$bbb,df$factor,FUN=cumsum)
```

I need to change a relatively minor thing now though. I want to ignore the first value of each group in the cumulative sum.

```
## At the moment the output is
[1]  2  6 12  3  8 15
## The output I need is
[1] 0 4 10  0 5 12
```

My thoughts so far have been:

Find some additional functionality in ave(), such as, slip in a [2:length] in an appropriate place, which I havent managed so far.

Do the ave() function as I did, then afterwards subtract the first bbb of each group from all the cumulative sum values of that group. The problem with that is, that I dont know how to target the first value of each group based on the factor.

Or I assume that it could more professionally be done with split/tapply or some other apply function.

This actually brings me to an additional question: where do I find information on functions other than e.g. `?ave`? It doesnt mention the functions I can use for it and the fact I can use `FUN=cumsum` I only know thanks to this forum. Or should this be common knowledge because it mentions the term 'function' on the help page? I am also having trouble finding comprehensive info on packages, other than youtube tutorials. I assume, for example, that dyplr would have some sort of elegant solution to my problem as well. I just dont know how to get to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can remove the first element, get the `cumsum` of the rest and concatenate with 0 inside the `FUN` of `ave`

```
with(df, ave(bbb, factor, FUN = function(x) c(0, cumsum(x[-1]))))
#[1]  0  4 10  0  5 12
```

---

With `dplyr`, we can use the same logic of concatenation as above

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(factor) %>% 
   mutate(cumbbb = c(0, cumsum(bbb[-1])))
```

Or create a logical index with `row_number()`, multiply by 'bbb' to get the first value 0 (as `FALSE` is 0 and `TRUE` is 1) before doing the `cumsum`

```
df %>%
    group_by(factor) %>% 
    mutate(cumbbb = cumsum((row_number() > 1) * bbb))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups: factor [2]
#    bbb factor cumbbb
#  <dbl> <fctr>  <dbl>
#1  2.00 1        0   
#2  4.00 1        4.00
#3  6.00 1       10.0 
#4  3.00 2        0   
#5  5.00 2        5.00
#6  7.00 2       12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using `dplyr`

```
bbb<-c(2,4,6,3,5,7)
factor<-gl(2,3)
df<-data.frame(bbb,factor)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(factor) %>%                                        # for each factor value
  mutate(cs = cumsum(ifelse(row_number() == 1, 0, bbb))) %>%  # replace bbb value in position 1 with 0 and get cumsum
  ungroup()                                                   # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#     bbb factor    cs
#   <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>
# 1    2. 1         0.
# 2    4. 1         4.
# 3    6. 1        10.
# 4    3. 2         0.
# 5    5. 2         5.
# 6    7. 2        12.
```